# OpenShift Origin Route Hostname not accessible

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-origin

I have a query which is basically a clarification regarding Routes in OpenShift Origin.

I managed to setup OpenShift Origin version 1.4.0-rc1 on a CentOS hosted in local VMWare installation. Am also able to pull and setup image for nginx and pod status shows Running. Able to access nginx on the service endpoint also. Now as per documentations if I want to access this nginx instance outside the hosted system I need to create a Route, which I also did.

Confusion is on the Create Route screen from OpenShift Web Console it generates a hostname or allows to enter a hostname. Both of the option i tried, generated hostname seems to be a a long subdomain kind of hostname and it doesn't work. What I mean is I'm not able to access this hostname from anywhere in the network including the hosting OS as well.

To summarize, service endpoints which looks like 172.x.x.x is working on the local machine which is hosting OpenShift. But the generated/entered hostname for the route doesn't work from anywhere.

Please clarify the idea behind this route concept and how could one access a service from outside the host machine (Part of same network)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in documentation:

> An OpenShift Origin route exposes a service at a host name, like
>   www.example.com, so that external clients can reach it by name. DNS
>   resolution for a host name is handled separately from routing; your
>   administrator may have configured a cloud domain that will always
>   correctly resolve to the OpenShift Origin router, or if using an
>   unrelated host name you may need to modify its DNS records
>   independently to resolve to the router.

It is important to notice the difference between "route" and "router". The Opensfhit router (that is mentioned above)listens to all requests  to Openshift deployed applications, and has to be previoulsy deployed, in order for routes to work.

https://docs.openshift.org/latest/architecture/core_concepts/routes.html

So once you have the router deployed and working, all routes that you create in openshift should resolve where that Openshift router is listening. For example, configuring your DNS with a wildcard (this is dnsmaq wildcard example):

```
address=/.yourdomain.com/107.117.239.50
```

This way all your "routes" to services should be like this:

- service1.yourdomain.com
- service2.yourdomain.com
- ...

Hope this helps